# auto arrow icon at the end of the sentence in a div

Tags: html, css

Need blue arrow after sentence end for a div it should auto display can we fix this with css

i found solution with css3 but i can't use css3 in this page

[image]

i am using a CMS and there is it's client who add and edit contain, can't write  server side language nor javascript

i thought it is easy to fix with css but i am finding impossible to if it now

Demo[Link](http://jsfiddle.net/mikulgohil/uF9fN/2/)

Comment: get that blue arrow image and put it :-)

Comment: p:after {content: " arrow.jpg";}

Comment: You need to provide more information. The basic answer is to just add the blue arrow at the end of your sentences, however if you need this to occur automatically you should add that to your description. If you're using a CMS or some type of framework, add that as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
p:after
{
    content: url('images/blue-arrow.png');
}
```

Assuming you save the blue arrow image at that location.

Comment: @mikul Then IE7 doesn't get the arrow. [Problem?](http://collerage.files.wordpress.com/2011/07/troll-face-problem.jpg) `:P`

Comment: :after is CSS2 I believe, but still may not be supported in IE7.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a best practice, but the only way to do this in ie7 (without a polyfill) is to add an inline element to the end of each p tag (on the inside) and give it the appropriate image styling.

ex:

HTML

```
<p> Lorem Ipsum... <span class="arrow"></span></p>
```

CSS

```
p span.arrow{
    display: inline-block; 
    background: url(img/arrow.png) no-repeat top left; 
    width: XXpx; 
    height: XXpx;
}
```